# In Promise of es6, '.catch(rejection)' is equal to '.then(null,rejection)'?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, frontend

Firstly,please look at this demo.

```js
function loadImageAsync(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = url;
    // onload 在对象已加载时触发
    image.onload = resolve;
    // onerror 在文档或图像加载过程中发生错误时被触发
    image.onerror = reject;

  })
}

var someImgEle = document.getElementById("imgEle");
var url = someImgEle.dataset.src
loadImageAsync(url).then(function() {
  someImgEle.src = url;
  someImg.style.display = "block";
  // error will be printed
}).catch(function() {
  console.log("error")
  throw new Error('couldnt load image' + url);
})
/*
loadImageAsync(url).then(function(){
 someImgEle.src = url;
 someImg.style.display = "block";
 // error will be not printed
 },function () {
  console.log("error")
  throw new Error('couldnt load image' + url);
 })
 */
```

```html
<img id="imgEle" src="" data-src="http://omizt4opc.bkt.clouddn.com/avatar.jpg" alt="">
```

In this demo, I think that "error" can't be printed. The fact hurts me.

Recently,I'm studying Promise by [url](http://es6.ruanyifeng.com/#docs/promise#Promise-prototype-catch).

But this demo seems conflictive to that.

I'm confused.

Comment: I don't understand why you think that error can't be printed.

Comment: to answer the question in the title (which seems to be separate from the text in the body of the question) ... yes, `.catch(onReject)` is exactly equal to `.then(null, onReject)` - but NOT the same as `.then(onFulfill, onReject)` - in fact, the polyfill I use has this bit of code in it `Promise.prototype.catch = function (onRejected) {
        return this.then(null, onRejected);
    };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `catch`:

```
.catch(function() {
  console.log("error")
  throw new Error('couldnt load image' + url);
})
```

both an error occurring during image load **and** inside `success` callback:

```
  someImgEle.src = url;
  someImg.style.display = "block";
  someImg.accessUndefinedProperty.oneLevelMore; // TypeError: Cannot read property 'oneLevelMore' of undefined
```

will be catched.

If you use `error callback` instead of a `catch` clause, only error during image load will be catched. The general recomendation is to use `catch` instead of error callbacks.

**Update:**

In your particular case, you have an error here:

```
someImg.style.display = "block";
```

since `someImg` is not defined, the `catch` block is executed. You can inspect an error by simply passing `error` object in `catch` block:

```
.catch(function(error) {
                ^^^^^
```

This particular case demonstrates why `catch` is preferred to `error callback`.

Comment: Only when errors occur , catch will be executed . I mean that there are not errors  during image load and inside success callback. So I don't understand that catch has been executed.

Comment: @may, ah, I get it now. It's triggered because you **do** have an error here ` someImg.style.display = "block";` - see my updated question. Also, don't forget you can upvote or accept my answer if it helped.

Comment: oh...................................I'm so sorry. I made a small but big mistake.I totally understand what you said ! Actually, I know catch is better than the callback of then. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

> Is `.catch(rejection)` equal to `.then(null,rejection)`?

Yes. And not only equal to, it's even implemented in terms of `then`.

However:

> ```
> loadImageAsync(url).then(function(){
>   // error here will be printed
> }).catch(function() {
>   console.log("error")
> })
> loadImageAsync(url).then(function(){
>  // error here will be not printed
> }, function () {
>   console.log("error")
> })
> ```

That's accurate. [`.then(…).catch(…)` and `.then(…, …)` are not equal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572).